# Short code not giving me desire output in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

**Plugin Code**

```
function myShortcode( $atts ) {  
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'cat' => '', ), $atts ) );  
    ob_start();  
    if ( $cat == '' ) { echo "Do Nothing!"; } 
    $output_string = ob_get_contents();  
    ob_end_clean();  
    return $output_string;  
}  
add_shortcode( mycatlist, myShortcode);
```

**Add below short code in post(in post section from wp-admin)**

```
    [mycatlist cat=4]
```

**Add below code in wordpress template file**

```
    <?php echo do_shortcode("[mycatlist]"); ?>
```

**i m getting that output** Do Nothing!

but i want to get cat value i mean 4

Comment: @Mark. yes i tried , but not working

Comment: I don't understand why do you need `ob_` in this code. ::::: What does *"Give me output"* and *"Need Output"* represent? :::: As far as I can see, the first example (`[mycatlist cat=4]`) has an empty output and the second (`do_shortcode("[mycatlist]")`) should output `Do Nothing!`...

Comment: @brasofilo please check again my edited question

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted has a lot of code that has not much to do with your test scenario. Simplify it to this:

```
 function myShortcode( $atts ) {  

    // maybe add some debugging?
    // print_r($atts);

    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'cat' => '', ), $atts ) );  
    return $cat;
 }  
 add_shortcode( 'mycatlist', 'myShortcode');
```

Now call it like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[mycatlist cat=\"4\"]"); ?>
```

It should print 4 on your page.

Comment: Not that code  <?php echo do_shortcode("[mycatlist cat=\"4\"]"); ?> cant work for me , bcoz i m using that code in template page, i m using that template page for lot of page when i create page from admin